# How to play video file from server in android native video player?

Tags: java, android, file

How can I directly load the video file from server without completely downloading whole file to phone storage. I don't want to use videoview also. I just want to call the native video player from device and play in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, you can just call mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://wwww.yourvideourl.mp4");

The following network protocols are supported for audio and video playback:

```
RTSP (RTP, SDP)
HTTP/HTTPS progressive streaming
HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol:
MPEG-2 TS media files only
Protocol version 3 (Android 4.0 and above)
Protocol version 2 (Android 3.x)
```

**And these are not supported before Android 3.0**

Detail info could be found at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html